# How to exclude unspecified form items from HTML GET request

Tags: html, forms, get

When you submit an HTML form with method='get', the values from the form get formatted into a GET request like

```
www.site.com/script.php?var1=value&var2=value&...
```

As far as I can tell, if any of the items on the form are unspecified, they still get put into the string. If var1 in the example above was unspecified, you'd see...

```
www.site.com/script.php?var1=&var2=value&...
```

Is there a way to make the form not include any unspecified values in the GET request (preferably without javascript)?

Comment: its not possible to do that, could you describe the need?

Comment: No real "need." I just like things to look clean. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do that. You can process the sent variables easily with PHP. But if you are really keen on doing so, you can use jQuery.

Anyways you could do something like this:

```
<form action="index.html" method="get">
    <input name="name">
    <input name="name2">
    <input name="name3">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $("form input").each(function(index, element) {
            if(($(this).val()=="")){ $(this).attr("disabled","disabled"); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But remember, this is not a good practice!